# Extend Screen for my laptop from 1366 x 768 to 1680 x1050

Tags: laptop, resolution

I need to find some software that creates a Virtual Screen size of 1680 x 1050 even though the screen only supports 1366 x 768.

It can scroll, but it needs to scroll to a maximum of 1680 x 1050 as we have software that needs to run at that resolution.

Any ideas, ive tried a few things

Infinate_Screen
DEXpot

but these dont seem to do what i need it to do

The laptop only has a standard graphics card. i.e a basic intel

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows support Downscaling, that dows exactly what you need:
It will increase the resolution as seen from the OS, and the monitor will scroll.

Open Regedit and look for "Display1_DownScalingSupported".
Set this parameter to 1 for all entries you will find

*// I used it only on netbooks to run "metro apps", but I noticed that it doesn't work on all systems*

*Remember also that modifying your registry is always something you do at your own risk*